# pom.xml setting the version of the parent project

Tags: maven-3

In our pom.xml, I need to set the version of the parent project to an environment variable:

example:

```
   <parent>
     <groupId>edu.university.se.se_parent_project</groupId>
     <artifactId>SE_ParentProject</artifactId>
     <version>${parent.version}</version>  
     <relativePath>../SE_ParentProject/pom.xml</relativePath>
   </parent>
```

How do I do that?

using ${parent.version}  is giving me this error:
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact edu.university.se.se_parent_project:SE_ParentProject:pom:${parent.version} from/to central

Comment: This is not possible and does not make sense, cause if it would be possible your build with this pom is never be reproducible.

Comment: Links to associated Maven issues showing not possible:  [forum](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Expand-environment-variable-in-parent-s-lt-version-gt-td127282.html) and [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2569), at least at time of writing. Current error on M 3.1.1 seems to back this up.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `${parent.version}` with `${env.PARENT_VERSION}` and add this environment variable to your OS

```
PARENT_VERSION=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```